# Issue with CouchbaseLite DB creation on Android - CORS issue

Tags: ionic-framework, webview, cors, couchbase-lite

I am working on developing an ionic app for android, that connects to CouchbaseLite and subsequently to Couchbase Server for data syncing. But due to a CORS error the CouchbaseLite DB (embedded db) in the mobile device is not getting created. So the first step itself is failing.

I am specifically looking for the Android mobiles

I traced the xhr request status, which is always 0. Tried to disable CORS by just removing the Webview (Uninstalled the pluign cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
Also tried making suitable changes in config.xml. None of these work.

refer this : 
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/cordova-couchbase/blob/master/src/database.ts
In this makeRequest function always fails with xhr request stats as 0.

Comment: This is a Hybrid app that we are trying to develop.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Couchbase Lite 1.x and as you can tell from the repo, there isn't any active development going on for past couple of years. Have you looked into Couchbase Lite 2.x and into either of the following options?

- Develop your own [Cordova native plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html) to use with Ionic app as discussed in this [example](https://docs.couchbase.com/tutorials/hotel-lister/introduction.html)
- Use this plugin from Ionic as discussed in this [example](https://ionicframework.com/blog/build-secure-offline-apps-with-ionic-couchbase-lite/)